# Upload an array in HANA

Tags: stored-procedures, hana

I am new to SAP HANA and was recently migrating some of our databases to it and found it very good in performance.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to upload an `array column` in HANA. But I found there is a way to INSERT an ARRAY in HANA using the method

```
  INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( 1, ARRAY ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) )
```

Since I have a `.CSV` file where the first two columns are integers and the third one is a bigint array  from `postgres` and the it looks like:

```
input.csv
1,2,"{1545645,2652656,3545645}"
3,4,"{155535,244564654,346456456,448484,5456456465,664654564}"
9,12,"{14645646,24564564,3478484,447984894,5464646,644458648,745464,849494,9494848}"
```

How is it possible to upload an array column in HANA(SPS 12)? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed here on SO before. Using the ARRAY() function is the **only** way to insert an ARRAY into an array-typed column.

If you want to load array data from a file you will have to use a custom loading program that constructs the ARRAY(....) function call for each record.

Depending on your use case, you might reconsider using other storage options for your data.

Comment: What do u mean by a custom loading program?Can u just explain how to load input.csv so that I will be able to understand the concept(Because my array has not a fixed size)

Comment: It means that you have to write a program, say in JAVA, that reads your CSV file and generates SQL INSERT statements out of the records it finds in the file. SAP HANA currently does not support array import/export with onboard methods.

Comment: So u mean if I have a 1 million records then I have to generate 1 million Insert  statements.Can't I use any Loops in SQL?

Comment: Yes, you need a separate statement for each record in this case, because you need to use the ARRAY() function and fill it with the values you want to insert. Generally, SQL doesn't support loops (no standard SQL does). There is a SQL extension available (SQL Script) that does support loops, but that doesn't help you here. If you are used to using ARRAYS in other DBMS, you want to ensure that you can work with them the same way in HANA before you take the effort and build your custom loading program. ARRAY support in HANA is not very strong...

Comment: Now I get it but Since U are from SAP could you please consider this doesn't affect HANA's usage because it is a very powerful Database but the support for array is not strong might be a drawback.Just a suggestion and thanks a lot for your explanation.

Comment: Hi RKR, even though I'm one of SAP's more than 80.000 employees, I'm not involved with the development of the SAP HANA platform. But there is the open SAP Ideas website: https://ideas.sap.com/SAPHANAPlatform where everyone can place ideas or change wishes. The development team will then consider these ideas.