# Creating a Column Store Table Type in HANA

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

I am trying to create a table type which has ARRAY as a column type in SAP HANA. When I use the standard DDL for creating the table type, i.e.

```
CREATE TYPE MYSCHEMA.TABNAME AS TABLE("ObjList" INTEGER ARRAY);
```

I get the following error :

> Could not execute 'CREATE TYPE "schema"."ListType" AS TABLE ( "ID" BIGINT      CS_FIXED, ...'
>
> SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: cannot create row table having array type: ObjList

It is unclear from the documentation how to create a table type of column store type. Since I am passing ARRAY value from .NET code to Stored procedure in HANA for bulk update/upsert, I cannot do away with this requirement.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create column table types - table types are always a row structure as they define how records should look like. Types don't store data, so there is no distinction between row/column/whatever here.

For what you want to do - handing ARRAYs from a client application to SAP HANA - this difference doesn't matter since it's simply not possible to do that. 
You can pass arrays between procedures/functions and tables, but no external interface can feed data into them.
Only with the `ARRAY()` function you can create arrays on the server-side. 
If you search for 'hana array' here on stackoverflow, you'll find that this has been discussed quite extensively already...

[Insert array in HANA with JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818409/insert-array-in-hana-with-java?s=1|2.1523) , [Upload an array in HANA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338263/upload-an-array-in-hana) or [How to insert an array in a loop to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625922/how-to-insert-an-array-in-a-loop-to-the-database/41673091#41673091) to list a few examples.

Comment: Thanks Lars! I am thinking of using a global temporary column table instead of a table type to handle the above. My doubt is since I am using ado.net's client API 's method `WriteToServer()` , I would be passing  a datatable to server. Can I define my source type as string and construct it as ARRAY(<value-list>) and send it using `WriteToServer()` , since I can leverage batch insert functionality which would be more efficient.

Comment: I tried passing a datatable as mentioned above in `WriteToServer()` method, which resulted in following  exception: `SELECT array on temporary table with GROUPBY, WHERE, ORDERBY is not supported` I am cluless as to what went wrong ..Is it due to the fact that datatable's source column has string as data type ?